# Firefox error console buffer size is too small

Tags: firefox

How to change the default Firefox error console buffer size? The problem is that there isn't enough time to read messages: old ones get overridden by the newer messages.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I know this is an old one, but this came up as my top search and the setting can now be found in the about:config settings.

Type about:config into the address bar and select ok to the dragons.

type this into the filter

```
devtools.hud.loglimit.console
```

Answer (score 2):

[AMO :: DevPrefs](https://web.archive.org/web/20181102224827/https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/devprefs/)

Can increase buffer size from the options panel of that addon:

[image]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.net](https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/previews/full/138/138434.png?modified=1403832544))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: There are two parts to this answer. The Console Service has one limit, which applies when the Error Console is closed. The Error Console has another limit, which applies when it is open. Normally these limits are both set to `250`.

It is not useful to have the Console Service limit is higher than the Error Console limit, since you need to open the Error Console in order to view the errors, but in theory you can do this by debugging the Firefox executable and setting a breakpoint on `xul!nsConsoleService::nsConsoleSerice` and set `mBufferSize` to a larger value. Symbols to allow you to do this are available on the [Mozilla symbol server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Mozilla_symbol_server).

You can increase the Error Console limit by editing the consoleBindings.xml file. This file is stored in one of the .jar files provided with Firefox ([omni.jar](http://shallowsky.com/blog/tech/web/firefox4-content-load.html) in Firefox 4). Note that editing a .jar file will stop partial updates from working, instead the Firefox updater will reinstall the full updated version.

Comment: Thanks, but I need this option in "user land".